# Using "in person" in a sentence

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

Can you use "in person" for inanimate objects, as in "the car looks completely different *in person*" implying the car is different than the picture?

Comment: It's not the car that is *in person* it is you who are viewing it *in person*.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, @Jim's comment means "yes, you can".

Comment: It's a bit odd, but understandable.

Comment: That is very idiomatic where I come from (US Midwest) and didn't think it odd until now.  Can't unread, CAN'T UNREAD! :-)